# How do I create a running difference in MS SQL based on groups of related rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently I have data like this:

| sequence | PART_NO | SHORT_QTY | PONUM | PO_QTY_REMAINING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | PIC16C711-20.P | -50 | 93148 | 75 |
| 7 | PIC16C711-20.P | -25 | 93148 | 75 |
| 83 | 2N4124 | -70 | 93116 | 1500 |
| 84 | 2N4124 | -500 | 93116 | 1500 |
| 85 | 2N4124 | -960 | 93116 | 1500 |
| 86 | 2N4124 | -500 | 93116 | 1500 |
| 87 | 2N4124 | -25 | 93116 | 1500 |

I want the data to look like this:

| sequence | PART_NO | SHORT_QTY | PONUM | PO_QTY_REMAINING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | PIC16C711-20.P | -50 | 93148 | 25 |
| 7 | PIC16C711-20.P | -25 | 93148 | 0 |
| 83 | 2N4124 | -70 | 93116 | 1430 |
| 84 | 2N4124 | -500 | 93116 | 930 |
| 85 | 2N4124 | -960 | 93116 | -30 |
| 86 | 2N4124 | -500 | 93116 | -530 |
| 87 | 2N4124 | -25 | 93116 | -555 |

I want the PO_QTY_REMAINING column to decrease by the SHORT_QTY amount of the PART_NO. Ultimately I plan on filtering out the rows with positive or 0 PO_QTY_REMAINING to only show the number of parts not covered by currently open purchase orders.

Comment: Please provide data and expected results as text in your question, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[How to ask a T-Sql question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: My apologies. Do not ask many questions on here. I have revised my question to include more acceptable table formats and ditched the images.

Comment: Can you add a description for the remaining qty calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't too difficult once you break it down into parts. First, for the first `sequence` item for each `PART_NO` you want to start with the value `PO_QTY_REMAINING + SHORT_QTY` to get what I will call the initial amount. Also, it will be handy to number the first record in each group of `PART_NO` records so we can find it - for this we can use the `ROW_NUMBER` function. Let's set up a simple script so you can follow - I will create a table variable and populate it with the sample data. With that in place, we can see what is going on. This is not the final answer, but I want to show how to get to the final answer. So let's start with this:

```
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE
(
    [sequence] INT NOT NULL,
    [PART_NO] VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    [SHORT_QTY] INT NOT NULL,
    [PONUM] INT NOT NULL,
    [PO_QTY_REMAINING] INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Data([sequence],[PART_NO],[SHORT_QTY],[PONUM],[PO_QTY_REMAINING])
VALUES
(6, 'PIC16C711-20.P', -50, 93148, 75),
(7, 'PIC16C711-20.P', -25, 93148, 75),
(83, '2N4124', -70, 93116, 1500),
(84, '2N4124', -500, 93116, 1500),
(85, '2N4124', -960, 93116, 1500),
(86, '2N4124', -500, 93116, 1500),
(87, '2N4124', -25, 93116, 1500);

SELECT [sequence],
       [PART_NO],
       [SHORT_QTY],
       [PONUM],
       [PO_QTY_REMAINING],
       [PO_QTY_REMAINING] + [SHORT_QTY] AS [initialSum],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PART_NO ORDER BY [sequence]) AS [num]
FROM @Data 
ORDER BY [sequence];
```

If you run this, the result look like this:

| sequence | PART_NO | SHORT_QTY | PONUM | PO_QTY_REMAINING | initialSum | num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | PIC16C711-20.P | -50 | 93148 | 75 | 25 | 1 |
| 7 | PIC16C711-20.P | -25 | 93148 | 75 | 50 | 2 |
| 83 | 2N4124 | -70 | 93116 | 1500 | 1430 | 1 |
| 84 | 2N4124 | -500 | 93116 | 1500 | 1000 | 2 |
| 85 | 2N4124 | -960 | 93116 | 1500 | 540 | 3 |
| 86 | 2N4124 | -500 | 93116 | 1500 | 1000 | 4 |
| 87 | 2N4124 | -25 | 93116 | 1500 | 1475 | 5 |

With the data in this form, what we want to do is calculate the running sum for each group of `PART_NO`. When the `num` is 1 for a `PART_NO`, we want to add the `initialSum`, otherwise we want to add `SHORT_QTY` to the running total. So we can use the `SUM` function and create partitions of `PART_NO` and order then by `sequence`. We will use a `CASE` statement to choose which field to add based on the logic we mentioned in this paragraph. So, I will treat the query above as a subquery and give it the poor name `sub` and we end up with:

```
SELECT sub.[sequence],
       sub.[PART_NO],
       sub.[SHORT_QTY],
       sub.[PONUM],
       SUM(   CASE
                  WHEN [num] = 1 THEN
                      [sub].[initialSum]
                  ELSE
                      [sub].[SHORT_QTY]
              END
          ) OVER (PARTITION BY sub.PART_NO ORDER BY [sub].[sequence]) AS [PO_QTY_REMAINING]
FROM
(
    SELECT [sequence],
           [PART_NO],
           [SHORT_QTY],
           [PONUM],
           [PO_QTY_REMAINING],
           [PO_QTY_REMAINING] + [SHORT_QTY] AS [initialSum],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PART_NO ORDER BY [sequence]) AS [num]
    FROM @Data
) AS sub
ORDER BY [sequence];
```

This gives the result that you wanted. I hope the explanation makes sense!